# How to find ammount of DRAM on NVME SSD

Tags: linux, command-line, nvme

So I recently changed my Linux system to a M.2 NVME SSD and the official documentation of the device only states that it has DRAM available (which I have confirmed with `nvme-cli`) but I can't find anywhere how to read the amount of DRAM available on the ssd itself. I'd like to know which command I can use to find out the available ammount of DRAM on the device.

EDIT
For short: I want to know how to check DRAM size on a M.2 NVME SSD

Comment: Ask the vendor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.